# usb_cam vidioc_streamon error 28

Tags: usb-cam, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I try to open up two video streams, I am getting an error stating that there is no space left on the device.

I know this is due to the bandwidth limitations of two cameras on one USB hub. I tried to lower the resolution of each camera, but this didn't help.

Did anybody use stereovision and successfully get two cameras to stream simultaneoulsy within ROS?

I am using usb_cam, but publishing two different topics.

thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12582/usb_cam-vidioc_streamon-error-28/) by [baseballmvp27](https://answers.ros.org/users/1558/baseballmvp27/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-01-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem and solved it as follow:

```
sudo rmmod uvcvideo
sudo modprobe uvcvideo quirks=128
```

After doing that, I can acquire images from 2 cameras at the same time.
Credits: http://renoirsrants.blogspot.com/2011/07/multiple-webcams-on-zoneminder.html
Checkout this link to see how to add this to your module conf so that changes become permanent.

However, using OpenCV to acquire images from the webcam still does not work. But using the usb_cam pkg, everything is fine.

---

Originally posted by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) with karma: 1001 on 2012-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unfortunately, your particular camera model may not work for this. USB devices must specify interface descriptors, and camera manufacturers often pick a terrible set of descriptor parameters that don't actually reflect the bandwidth saved by downsizing the image. If you run 'lsusb -v', you can search for the camera, and often find a number of things like:

```
Interface Descriptor:
  bLength                 9
  bDescriptorType         4
  bInterfaceNumber        1
  bAlternateSetting       4
  bNumEndpoints           1
  bInterfaceClass        14 Video
  bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
  bInterfaceProtocol      0 
  iInterface              0 
  Endpoint Descriptor:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType         5
    bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
    bmAttributes            5
      Transfer Type            Isochronous
      Synch Type               Asynchronous
      Usage Type               Data
    wMaxPacketSize     0x1400  3x 1024 bytes
    bInterval               1
```

If there isn't an appropriately-sized descriptor (one which is both large enough to handle your video stream, but small enough that 2 of them will not overload the bus), then the call to open fails. There are basically 3 things you can do about this:

1. Get each camera on a separate USB bus (this may be as simple as moving which ports they are plugged into, but it may also be impossible on your current computer).
2. Buy a different set of cameras, which have better choices for frame size.
3. Hack the usb driver (very advanced and not recommended). The reality is that the USB bus bandwidth calculation is based on the overly-sized estimate from the device, and is already leaving some extra bandwidth, and so you could probably hack the driver to always go ahead with the opening the endpoint even though the check fails. Before I started using the Kinect, I did do a bit of looking around at this (there is a usb video driver forum which has a lot of information), but decided that replacing the cameras with different ones was the easier approach.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2012-01-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on 2012-03-05**:
same problem here. I would go for suggestion 2, but what to look for exactly when buying the cameras? (there is typically not that much info on the box ...)

**Comment by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on 2012-03-06**:
A workaround is to open camera 1, grab, close, open camera 2, grab, close, and so on. There are 2 problems though: frame rate is about 1-2 fps, and the white balance mechanism does not work, resulting in a yellow image...